# TextMate: Anyway to browse/trace variables through classes/objects/files?

Tags: php, textmate, textmatebundles

Is there a addon where let say I want to see the origin/stack/trace of a variable I can do so?

I primarily want to see where variables are coming from, what classes and files they go through.

If there is another editor that does this well Ill take suggestions as well!

Thanks.

Comment: None of those follow classes outsided of the current file. I wanted to follow objects to the files being called in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think TextMate is able to do that, with or without a plugin.

*-- START EDIT --*

When I was still using it and I wanted to **see** (and possibly jump to) where a method or property came from I just used Search in Project.

*-- END EDIT --*

Vim in conjunction with ctags and cscope can help you jump from instance to prototype and vice-versa — wether it's in the current file or not — with `<C-]>` (or `<C-$>` on my french Mac keyboard); with TagList or TagBar you can see the structure of your code… but none of this can give you the clean overview you are looking for. But there is probably a [plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/index.php) for that.

But if that kind of features is important for you it is typically a good reason to use an IDE instead of a text editor. In Eclipse, for example, you have a Type Hierarchy view that does most of what you want and possibly other tools to do the rest. I haven't tried every single IDE under the sun but I think a similar or more powerful feature exists in all of them.

Maybe in Emacs…